Show that $|\rho|(E) = \max \{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rho(F_n): \{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \text{ is a countable partition of } E \}$
For $\rho$ a $\sigma-$finite signed measure over $(X, S)$, show that:
$$(i) \quad |\rho|(E) = \max \Big\{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rho(F_n): \{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \text{ is a countable partition of } E \Big\}, \quad \forall E \in S$$
and that
$$(ii) \quad |\rho|(E) = \sup \Big\{\int_E f d\rho: f \in \mathscr{L}_1(|\rho|), |f| \le 1 \Big\}, \quad \forall E \in S$$
Furthermore, if $|\rho|(E) < + \infty$, then in $(ii)$ $\sup$ can be replaced by $\max$.
Proof.
Let $E \in S$ and pick $\{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S$ a countable partition of  $E$. Our definition says that $|\rho| := \rho^+ + \rho^-: S \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a measure, where $\rho^+, \rho^-: S \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are the measures given by the Jordan Decomposition Theorem for signed measures. Since $|\rho(E)| \le |\rho|(E)$ for each $E \in S$,
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rho(F_n) = \rho(E) \le |\rho(E)| \le |\rho|(E), \quad \forall E \in S$$
which implies that
$$|\rho|(E) \ge \max \Big\{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rho(F_n): \{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \text{ is a countable partition of } E \Big\}, \quad \forall E \in S$$
While trying to prove the reverse inequality I noticed that an alternative definition of $|\rho|$ is given as follows:
$$|\rho|(E) = \sup \Big\{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |\rho(F_n)|: \{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \text{ is a countable partition of } E \Big\}, \quad \forall E \in S$$
Thus, it doesn't make me full sense to proof the other inequality. In other words, it is not clear for me how is the $\sigma-$finite property used for this. Nevertheless, here is what I've tried:

By Hahn Decomposition Theorem, there are disjoint sets $A, B \in S$ such that $X = A \cup B$, $A$ is positive for $\rho$ and $B$ is negative for $\rho$. Thus, $\{A \cap E, B \cap E\}$ is a countable partition of $E$. So,
$$|\rho|(E) = \rho^+(E) + \rho^-(E) = \rho^+(E \cap A) + \rho^+(E \cap B) + \rho^-(E \cap A) + \rho^-(E \cap B)$$
Since $A$ is positive for $\rho$, $\rho^-(E \cap A) = 0 = -\rho^-(E \cap A)$ and since $B$ is negative for $\rho$, $\rho^+(E \cap B) = 0 = - \rho^+(E \cap B)$. Thus,
$$|\rho|(E) = \rho^+(E \cap A) - \rho^-(E \cap A) - \Big( \rho^+(E \cap B) - \rho^-(E \cap B) \Big) = \rho(E \cap A) - \rho(E \cap B)$$
He have that $\rho(E \cap A) \ge 0$ and $\rho(E \cap B) \le 0$ since $A$ is positive and $B$ is negative for $\rho$. Thus,
$$\rho(E \cap A) - \rho(E \cap B) = |\rho(E \cap A)| + |\rho(E \cap B)|$$
Thus, the existence of partition $\{E \cap A, E \cap B\}$ implies that
$$|\rho|(E) \le \sup \Big\{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |\rho(F_n)|: \{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \text{ is a countable partition of } E \Big\}$$

For the second part, we firstly note that for $X = A \cup B$ where $(A | B)$ is a Hahn Decomposition,
$$|\rho|(E) = \rho^+(E \cap A) + \rho^+(E \cap B) + \rho^-(E \cap A) + \rho^-(E \cap B) = \int_E \mathbb{1}_{E \cap A} d\rho^+ + \int_E \mathbb{1}_{E \cap B} d\rho^+ + \int_E \mathbb{1}_{E \cap A} d\rho^- + \int_E \mathbb{1}_{E \cap B} d\rho^- = \int_E |f| d\rho^+ + \int_E |f| d\rho^- = \int_E |f| d|\rho|$$
where $f^+ = \mathbb{1}_{E \cap A}$ and $f^- = \mathbb{1}_{E \cap B}$.
I intuitively understand that, by $(i)$, as $f$ can be expressed as a limit of some $S-$simple functions sequence, then $(ii)$ holds.

I'm looking for some clarification speaking about the veracity of part $(i)$ and the intuitively sketch for part $(ii)$.
I don't clearly see why it only holds for $|f| \le 1$. Of course I don't clearly see why $(ii)$ holds for the $\max$ operator when $|\rho|(E) < + \infty$ and $\rho$ is $\sigma-$finite signed measure.

Linked answers.
$|\mu|(E) = \sup\{|\int_E f\,d\mu | ; |f|\leq 1 \}$, total variation of a measure.

Part $(i)$ is false. The right expression is $$|\rho|(E) = \sup \Big{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |\rho(F_n)|: {F_n}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \text{ is a countable partition of } E \Big}, \quad \forall E \in S$$

@Ramiro yes, as I read, that it an alternatively definition for the total variation measure. Even though the space is sigma-finite, it is not possible to say that the set of partitions of a E are finite, right?

Right. Even if the measure space had finite measure, the set of partitions can be infinite (and even uncountable).
